# Rails stored images. Table design. Active admin and paperclip

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, paperclip, activeadmin

I want an opinion and the Rails way to do something.

I have a Rails 3 application that uses active_admin gem. These app has some models. These models have one to many relationships with images.  i.e. model A has many images, model B has many images, model C has many images.

I want to use paperclip (or another option) to store this images.
I want to store all those images (from different entities) in the same table. 
In that table, i have to reference the entity using two columns (entity_type -A or B or C-, entity_id ). I cannot have a real foreign key because I don´t know which table I reference.

Questions are:
- What do you think about this database structure?
- How would you implement the image uploading functions using active_admin? In each model tab or an active admin model for the images and upload images for all models in the same tab?
- How can I implement that?

Comment: re: the described model structure, what you're describing is a polymorphic belongs_to association -- look it up in the Rails API docs; it's a pretty common pattern, easy to use and pretty much transparent to boot.

Comment: How it integrates with active_admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/599 and then Macfanatics answer. It describes setting up a polymorphic association and how to use this within activeadmin.